# Angular Material Pre rendered Dialog Issue

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am trying to use pre rendered dialog box  but there is some sort of error I think .

I have used HTML as

```
<div style="visibility: hidden">
        <div class="md-dialog-container" id="myDialog">
            <md-dialog layout-padding="" aria-label="myDialog">
                <h2>Pre-Rendered Dialog</h2>
                <p>
                    This is a pre-rendered dialog, which means that <code>$mdDialog</code> doesn't compile its
                    template on each opening.
                    <br><br>
                    The Dialog Element is a static element in the DOM, which is just visually hidden.<br>
                    Once the dialog opens, we just fetch the element from the DOM into our dialog and upon close
                    we restore the element back into its old DOM position.
                </p>
            </md-dialog>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also My JAvascript contains following code

```
$scope.showPrerenderedDialog = function (ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            contentElement: '#myDialog',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        });
    };

    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.hide = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $mdDialog.cancel();
        };

        $scope.answer = function (answer) {
            $mdDialog.hide(answer);
        };
    }
```

Any help ?

Comment: are you getting any errors in console ? or what is happening, does the dialog not open, it fails silently or what?

Comment: Im having the same issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes I have figured it out . You need to add the latest version of angular material i.e. RC version . It will work fine after that

Answer (score 0):

So as Vishal pointed out, you need to the latest version of angular material. In my case, 1.1.0-RC2 wasn't enough. I switched over to 1.1.0-RC5 and everything worked as expected.

The latest release can be found here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#angular-material